# Add item from array to list when button is clicked in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a UI where a user can select from a list, include the selection in an array and then display the array in another list. I'm very close. However, every time I add an item to the list it repeats items.

How do I clear the list before it builds from the array again.

You can see how it works and my code here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = [];
    
  $(".btn").click(function(){
 a.push($(this).next("span").text());
 $(this).closest("li").hide();
    $( "#s" ).text( a.join( " " ) );

    $.each(a, function(i){
        var cList = $('ul.mylist');
     var li = $('<li/>')
         .addClass('ui-menu-item')
            .attr('role', 'menuitem')
            .appendTo(cList);
        var aaa = $('<a/>')
            .addClass('ui-all')
            .text(a[i])
            .appendTo(li);      
        });   
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Selector</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>List of Options</h2>
      <ul>
         <li><button class="btn">Select</button><span>One</span></li>
         <li><button  class="btn">Select</button><span>Two</span></li>
         <li><button class="btn">Select</button><span>Three</span></li>
         <li><button class="btn">Select</button><span>Four</span></li>
      </ul>
      <h2>List of Selections</h2>
      <ul class="mylist"> 
      </ul>
      <h2>Array</h2>
      <div>Array of Selected Items to Send to DB:</div>
      <span ID="s"></span>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to empty the Ul html first because you make a each function which append all values of array again and again so it repeat the values.
You can see live demo here :- https://jsfiddle.net/Arsh_kalsi01/15zhk00y/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var a = [];

 

 $(".btn").click(function(){
  var obj = $(this);
 a.push(obj.next("span").text());
  console.log(a);
 obj.parent().hide();
   $( "#s" ).text( a.join( " " ) );
$('ul.mylist').html("");
    $.each(a, function(i){
        var cList = $('ul.mylist');
     var li = $('<li/>')
         .addClass('ui-menu-item')
            .attr('role', 'menuitem')
            .appendTo(cList);
        var aaa = $('<a/>')
            .addClass('ui-all')
            .text(a[i])
            .appendTo(li);      
        });   
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Selector</title>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>List of Options</h2>
<ul>
    <li><button class="btn">Select</button><span>One</span></li>
    <li><button  class="btn">Select</button><span>Two</span></li>
    <li><button class="btn">Select</button><span>Three</span></li>
    <li><button class="btn">Select</button><span>Four</span></li>
</ul>
<h2>List of Selections</h2>
<ul class="mylist"> 
</ul>
<h2>Array</h2>
<div>Array of Selected Items to Send to DB:</div>
<span ID="s"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.empty` (See [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)).

It will empty out the contents of the selected node.

You can do that before you start iterating in the array and your code will behave as you expected it to.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = [];
    
  $(".btn").click(function(){
 a.push($(this).next("span").text());
 $(this).closest("li").hide();
    $( "#s" ).text( a.join( " " ) );

    // change here:
    $('ul.mylist').empty();
    $.each(a, function(i){
        var cList = $('ul.mylist');
     var li = $('<li/>')
         .addClass('ui-menu-item')
            .attr('role', 'menuitem')
            .appendTo(cList);
        var aaa = $('<a/>')
            .addClass('ui-all')
            .text(a[i])
            .appendTo(li);      
        });   
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Selector</title>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>List of Options</h2>
<ul>
    <li><button class="btn">Select</button><span>One</span></li>
    <li><button  class="btn">Select</button><span>Two</span></li>
    <li><button class="btn">Select</button><span>Three</span></li>
    <li><button class="btn">Select</button><span>Four</span></li>
</ul>
<h2>List of Selections</h2>
<ul class="mylist"> 
</ul>
<h2>Array</h2>
<div>Array of Selected Items to Send to DB:</div>
<span ID="s"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just empty the list before you start appending to it using `cList.html('')` before the `$.each` (where you shoud define `cList` because no need to redefine it inside `$.each` for each element):

```
var cList = $('ul.mylist');
// clear the content of the list, now the list is empty and ready to be filled again
cList.html('');
$.each(a, function(i){
    var li = $('<li/>')
        .addClass('ui-menu-item')
        .attr('role', 'menuitem')
        .appendTo(cList);
    var aaa = $('<a/>')
        .addClass('ui-all')
        .text(a[i])
        .appendTo(li);      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your issue just put the null or empty array a[] inside the button click and it will clear itself;

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = [];
    
  $(".btn").click(function(){
    a=[];
 a.push($(this).next("span").text());
 $(this).closest("li").hide();
    $( "#s" ).text( a.join( " " ) );

    $.each(a, function(i){
        var cList = $('ul.mylist');
     var li = $('<li/>')
         .addClass('ui-menu-item')
            .attr('role', 'menuitem')
            .appendTo(cList);
        var aaa = $('<a/>')
            .addClass('ui-all')
            .text(a[i])
            .appendTo(li);      
        });   
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Selector</title>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>List of Options</h2>
<ul>
    <li><button class="btn">Select</button><span>One</span></li>
    <li><button  class="btn">Select</button><span>Two</span></li>
    <li><button class="btn">Select</button><span>Three</span></li>
    <li><button class="btn">Select</button><span>Four</span></li>
</ul>
<h2>List of Selections</h2>
<ul class="mylist"> 
</ul>
<h2>Array</h2>
<div>Array of Selected Items to Send to DB:</div>
<span ID="s"></span>
</body>
</html>
```